# Are 2x2 matrices on a Euclidean domain a Euclidean domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-domain

Let $M(R)$ be the set of 2x2 matrices with elements of ring $R$.  $M(R)$ is obviously a ring also.  But if $R$ is a Euclidean domain, is $M(R)$ also a eucliean domain?  If it is, how do you perform the division algorithm, and what is the notion of "degree"?

My understanding of a Euclidean domain:

- a ring $R$, with $+$ and $\cdot$ operations, $\mathbb{0}$ and $\mathbb{1}$ values, an additive inverse operation, and distributive properties
- a division operator suitable for use with an extended $\gcd$ algorithm.  (for any $a$ and nonzero $b$ in $R$, it produces $q$ and $r$ such that $a = qb + r$ and the "degree" of r is smaller than the "degree" of b so that the extended gcd algorithm is guaranteed to terminate).

The extended gcd algorithm, given any $a$ and $b$ in $R$, uses the division operator of a Euclidean domain to produce $(g, x, y, a', b')$ such that:

- $g = \gcd(a,b)$
- $a = ga'$
- $b = gb'$
- $a'x + b'y = \mathbb{1}$ and $ax + by = g$.

I'm trying to create a division algorithm for $M(R)$.

Any matrix $\mathbf{B} \in M(R)$ can be factored into Smith Normal Form where $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{X}\mathbf{B'}\mathbf{Y}$, $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are easily invertible and have determinant of $\mathbb{1}$, and $\mathbf{B'}$ is diagonal.  This can be used to reduce the complexity of the division problem to only the case where the denominator is a diagonal matrix.

I'm having trouble getting past this point.  Given arbitrary $\mathbf{A}$ and nonzero diagonal matrix $\mathbf{B}$, how do you find $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ such that $\mathbf{A} =  \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{R}$ and what is the notion of degree such that $\mathrm{degree}(\mathbf{R}) < \mathrm{degree}(\mathbf{B})$?

Comment: $M(R)$ is never a *domain* for $n\ge2$.

Comment: A Euclidean domain is an integral domain, which is commutative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$M_2(\mathbb Z)$ is not commutative and has zero divisors. Very far from a domain.

Comment: Thanks.  I spent a lot of time on this, thus demonstrating the hazard of learning mathematical topics from Wikipedia.